# How to stop a Function from Running in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a function that starts playing an animation that is running asynchronously (in the background). This animation is called indefinitely using a completion handler (see below).  Is there a way to close this function upon pressing another button?

Here is my code:

```
func showAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        animate1(imageView: self.Anime, images: self.animation1)
    }, completion: { (true) in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            self.showAnimation() // replay first showAnimation
        }
    }) 
 }
```

Then upon pressing another button we closeout the above function

```
showAnimation().stop();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a property to the class to act as a flag indicating whether the animation should be run or not.

```
var runAnimation = true

func showAnimation() {
    if !runAnimation { return }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        animate1(imageView: self.Anime, images: self.animation1)
    }, completion: { (true) in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            if runAnimation {
                self.showAnimation() // replay first showAnimation
            }
        }
    }) 
}
```

Then in the button handler to stop the animation you simply do:

```
runAnimation = false
```

Note that this does not stop the currently running 1 second animation. This just prevent any more animations.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of ways to do this. The simplest is to have a Boolean property (which you should make properly atomic) that you check in your `asyncAfter` block, and don't just don't call `showAnimation()` again if it's true.

Another thing you can do, and what I like to do for more complex tasks, is to use `OperationQueue` instead of `DispatchQueue`. This allows you to cancel operations, either individually or all at once, or even suspend the whole queue (obviously don't suspend the main queue or call `removeAllOperations()` on it, though, since there may be other operations in there unrelated to your code).

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a variable outside of your function, then observe its value and handle your task. I can give you a solution:

```
class SomeClass {

    private var shouldStopMyFunction: Bool = false // keep this private

    public var deadline: TimeInterval = 0

    func stopMyFunction() {
        shouldStopMyFunction = true
    }

    func myFunction(completionHanlder: @escaping (String)->()) {
        // -------
        var isTaskRunning = true
        func checkStop() {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                if self.shouldStopMyFunction, isTaskRunning {
                    isTaskRunning = false
                    completionHanlder("myFunction is forced to stop! ")
                } else {
                    //print("Checking...")
                    checkStop()
                }
            }
        }
        checkStop()
        // --------


        // Start your task from here

        DispatchQueue.global().async { // an async task for an example.
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.deadline, execute: {
                guard isTaskRunning else { return }
                isTaskRunning = false
                completionHanlder("My job takes \(self.deadline) seconds to finish")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And implement:

```
let anObject = SomeClass()
anObject.deadline = 5.0 // seconds

anObject.myFunction { result in
    print(result)
}

let waitingTimeInterval = 3.0 // 6.0 // see `anObject.deadline`
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + waitingTimeInterval) {
    anObject.stopMyFunction()
}
```

Result with `waitingTimeInterval = 3.0`: `myFunction is forced to stop!`

Result with `waitingTimeInterval = 6.0`: `My job takes 5.0 seconds to finish`